# What are the limits of Drax's abilities?

Tags: marvel, comics, guardians-of-the-galaxy

I was struck by how much Drax was struck in Guardians of the Galaxy Volume 2.

His durability is much higher than I presumed, but he doesn't seem to have the strength that we see in Gamora.

In the comics, what exactly are his abilities, or the abilities of his race, and *what are their limits*?

Comment: Limits of power usually aren't clear or permanent in superhero genre.

Comment: @Mithoron We can generally assume the limit is the most extreme observed example until something proves otherwise, which is all I need

Comment: He can blend with his surroundings by moving veeeeeryyy sloooooowlyyy...

Answer (score 4):

In the comics, he was once a human named Arthur Douglas, whose spirit was placed inside an other powerful body, and then Drax the destroyer was created.
Unlike the movie version, when he was human, his family was killed by Thanos, instead of Ronan.

In the early comics when he was introduced in the Marvel universe, he had the ability to fly and could also shoot energy blasts.
But when he became a member of the Guardians of Galaxy (relaunched series), he lost the flight ability and the power of energy blasts.

Now he just has great strength and strong senses and likes to use knives in battles, even though he's not that much of an expert in fighting with them. But he once passed through Thanos's force field (I don't remember what issue it was), so I guess he has some great superhuman strength !

I read somewhere that he was made by Gods to kill 'the mad titan Thanos', that's why he's called the Destroyer. I'm not sure if he's same in the movie version.

Comment: So what can he do?

Comment: Now he just has great strength and strong senses and likes to use knives in battles, even though he's not that much of an expert in fighting with them.
But he once passed through Thanos's force field (I don't remember what issue it was), so I guess he has some great superhuman strength

Comment: Well that's what the answer section is for! Go on!